# React Link element causing the app to fail

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just started to build this shopping cart project. and I am able to display the components fine when I manually change the url but -- When I add the Link element to the Nav my app stops working. Why is that happening?

I want to the display the different components when they are clicked.

When I add the Link Element to the navigation bar I get the following errors in the console:

`The above error occurred in the <Link> component`

`Uncaught Error: useHref() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.`

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

function Nav () {
    return (
        <nav>
            
            <h3>Logo</h3>
            <ul>
                <Link to="/home">
                    <li>Home</li>
                </Link>
                <Link to="/shop">
                    <li>Shop</li>
                </Link>
                <Link to="/cart">
                    <li>Cart</li>
                </Link>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    )
}

export default Nav;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './components/main/Home'
import Cart from './components/main/Cart'
import Shop from './components/main/Shop'
import About from './components/main/About'

function RouteSwitch() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
          <Route path='/' exact element={<Home />} />
          <Route path='/shop' element={<Shop />} />
          <Route path='/about' element={<About />} />
          <Route path='/cart' element={<Cart />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default RouteSwitch;
```

```
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import RouteSwitch from './RouteSwitch';
import Nav from './components/Nav'
import Footer from './components/Footer';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Nav/>
      <RouteSwitch />
      <Footer/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Pretty sure you need to have `<BrowserRouter>` wrap all router-related components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `nav` component must be inside of `Router` component.

```js
<BrowserRouter>
      <Nav /> // here
      <Routes>
          <Route path='/' exact element={<Home />} />
          <Route path='/shop' element={<Shop />} />
          <Route path='/about' element={<About />} />
          <Route path='/cart' element={<Cart />} />
      </Routes>
      <Footer />
</BrowserRouter>
```